# How to get all elements of a selection

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

This is my editor content:

```
<h1>Heading 1<h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
```

Now if i select text in the editor, is there a chance to get a list of all the elements involved in this selection? For example if i select a portion of Heading 1 and Paragraph i would like to get an array (h1, p) or at least an object where i can see which elements are in the selection.

Ive already tried most of the functions described here http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection but most of the time i only get the first element of the selection.

Answer (score 0):

i have adapted a function i had for the same

```
$("textarea").select(function() {
  var textComponent = $(this)[0]; //element identifier
  var selectedText;
  // IE version
  if (document.selection !== undefined)
  {
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  // Mozilla version
  else if (textComponent.selectionStart !== undefined)
  {
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
  }
  $("p").html("You selected: " + selectedText);
});
```

check here: https://jsfiddle.net/ees8bupq/1/